# How could Add wideget by loop python PyQt5

Tags: python, for-loop, pyqt5, widget

Hej : I am trying to display images in QLabel widgets in PyQt by loop , because i it is not just one img ,so how could we make i For loop in order to display those images in label and put them in gridview layout .
With my all regards and hop for help

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to ask specific question and also read [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Your question is really simple and you could have just googled it and found your answer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1020, 950)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        
        
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1020, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
        for i in range(0,3): # set number of images
            
            imageName="image"+str(i)
        
            Pixmap=QPixmap(imageName)
            self.label.setPixmap(Pixmap)
            self.label_2.setPixmap(Pixmap)
            self.label_3.setPixmap(Pixmap)
            self.label_4.setPixmap(Pixmap)
            
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```